# Can I verify RSA signatures inside of solana program?

Tags: solana-program, signature

I want to check RSA signature inside of a program, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The network only provides "builtin" programs for validating ed25519 and secp256k1 signatures, at https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#ed25519-program and https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#secp256k1-program

You can try to use a crypto library on-chain that does RSA signature verification, but you will most likely run out of compute units. I'm not a cryptography expert, but I do know that signature verification is typically an expensive operation.