Does solana support offchain sign tx ,and verify onchian ,like eip712 in eth
Does solana support offchain sign tx ,and verify onchian ,like eip712 in eth
like this
  function delegateBySig(address delegatee, uint nonce, uint expiry, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public {
        bytes32 domainSeparator = keccak256(abi.encode(DOMAIN_TYPEHASH, keccak256(bytes(name)), getChainId(), address(this)));
        bytes32 structHash = keccak256(abi.encode(DELEGATION_TYPEHASH, delegatee, nonce, expiry));
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19\x01", domainSeparator, structHash));
        address signatory = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
        require(signatory != address(0), "Uni::delegateBySig: invalid signature");
        require(nonce == nonces[signatory]++, "Uni::delegateBySig: invalid nonce");
        require(now <= expiry, "Uni::delegateBySig: signature expired");
        return _delegate(signatory, delegatee);
    }
    ```


I am unfamiliar with eip712, but going by your question,

solana does support off-chain transaction signing, check out https://docs.solanalabs.com/proposals/off-chain-message-signing#:~:text=Solana%20off%2Dchain%20messages%20MUST,the%20result%20is%20ed25519%20signed and a CLI walkthrough here https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/examples/sign-offchain-message#:~:text=To%20ensure%20that%20off%2Dchain,in%20a%20transaction%20MessageHeader%20today.

As for on-chain verification, it seems that doing so is supported using external libraries and an expensive operation as per Jon C's answer here https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/6296/1708


